# Boost Locale – accessing ICU functions directly

Tags: c++, icu, boost-locale

I recently began using Boost Locale traversing and boundary analysis of Unicode strings.  I’ve used some of the features available for case conversion, i.e.: **to_upper()**, which appears to wrap ICU’s toUpper() function.

I didn't find Boost Locale wrappers for other ICU functions such as **u_isalpha()** or **u_isalnum()**.  How can I these use these ICU functions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend on how you're building Boost.Locale & linking against ICU. If for example you're linking against dynamic ICU libraries (e.g. Boost dll/so/dylib relies on ICU dll/so/dylib) or linking in ICU directly to satisfy the dependency, then you simply need to include the proper ICU header(s) and call the APIs.

For example, [u_isalpha()](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uchar_8h.html#a86cc4f937e33bcea3772c6faf3e293c1) is found in [uchar.h](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uchar_8h.html)